# lua os.execute doesn't work if the script runs from /etc/rc.local

Tags: bash, curl, lua, init

I have this simple lua script that listens for a particular event and then fire a POST request to the twilio.com web service to start a call and then send a mail.

```
#!/usr/bin/lua
-- February 2015, Suxsem

local sock      = require("socket")
local mosq      = require("mosquitto")

local mqtt = mosq.new("sonny_lua_scattato", true)
mqtt:login_set("***", "***")

local call = function (from, to)
        os.execute([[curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/***/Calls.json' \
                --data-urlencode 'To=]] .. to .. [[' \
                --data-urlencode 'From=]] .. from .. [[' \
                -d 'Url=https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/' \
                -d 'Method=GET' \
                -d 'FallbackMethod=GET' \
                -d 'StatusCallbackMethod=GET' \
                -d 'Timeout=20' \
                -d 'Record=false' \
                -u ***:***> twiliolog.txt]])
end

local callback = function (mid, topic, message)
        print("Received: " .. topic .. ": " .. message)

            if topic == "ArseniAlarm/Scattato" then

                local call_from = "+393317893***"
                local call_to = {"+393299573***",
                                      "+393473621***",
                                      "+393492829***"}

                for i, to in ipairs(call_to) do
                        call(call_from, to)
                end

                local rcpt = {"semer***.stef***@hotmail.it",
                                "miky.semer***@live.it"}

                local sbj = "ANTIFURTO ARSENI"
                local bdy = "ANTIFURTO ARSENI - " .. os.date("%T - %d/%m/%Y")
                os.execute('echo -e "To: ' .. table.concat(rcpt, ",") .. '\r\nSubject: ' .. sbj .. '\r\n\r\n' .. bdy .. '" | msmtp --from=default -t')

        end

end

mqtt:callback_set("ON_MESSAGE", callback)

local connected = false

mqtt:callback_set("ON_CONNECT", function ()
        print("Connected")
        connected = true
        mqtt:subscribe("ArseniAlarm/Scattato", 2)
end)
mqtt:callback_set("ON_DISCONNECT", function ()
        print("Disconnected")
        connected = false
end)

mqtt:connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)

while true do
        mqtt:loop()
        if connected then
                sock.sleep(1.0) -- seconds
        else
                sock.sleep(5.0)
                mqtt:reconnect()
        end
end
```

Now... I run the script with the following command:

```
cd /root/mqtt_client/ ; lua /root/mqtt_client/mqtt_scattato.lua &
```

Everything works good, i receive tha call and the mail and in twiliolog.txt (if you look at the code I do "curl ... > twiliolog.txt" to start the call) I can see the twilio response.

BUT

If i put the same command (cd /root/mqtt_client/ ; lua /root/mqtt_client/mqtt_scattato.lua &) inside /etc/rc.local something strange happens:
1) i receive the mail but NOT the call!
2) twiliolog.txt (output of curl) is correctly created but it's empty!

My platform is a router with openwrt barrier breaker.

I really hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: probably file permission issue?

Comment: umh i think openwrt runs all from the root user

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the os.execute call entirely.
I'm now using lua native https sockets:

```
local https = require("ssl.https")
local call = function (from, to)
        local body = "To=" .. to .. "&From=" .. from .. "&Url=https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/&Timeout=20&Record=false"
        https.request {
                protocol = "tlsv1",
                method="POST",
                url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/***/Calls.json",
                source=ltn12.source.string(body),
                headers = {["content-length"] = #body, ["content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
                user="***",
                password="***",
        }
end
```

I'm still using os.execute to send the mail and it works fine, so i think that the problem is related to the combination of curl + os.execute + start script on boot.

I have still no clue about what problem could cause this behaviour